# Wordpress filter for wp_title not being executed

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I'm attempting to modify the title tag of a Wordpress blog for SEO purposes, however it does not seem like my filter is even being executed. To rule out any other bugs I wrote a simple snippet that should change the title of every page to 'foo'

```
// functions.php
function seo_filter_title($title) {
  return 'foo';
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'seo_filter_title');

// header.php
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

However even this simple snippet is not working.

Comment: I'd suggest swapping the `return 'foo'` with `exit`. It'll tell you if your function is being called, at least.

Comment: If your function is being called, maybe is just a "priority problem" ?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter, add a 3rd parameter to your "add_filter function".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was a priority issue. There was a conflicting filter, so adjusting the priority and removing the other filter did the trick.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter